# A program/app that allows to explain/teach over Youtube?

Tags: educational

Where can I find programs/apps like the person in this Youtube video is using:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKvnmxte98A

I don't even know how they're called so I'm not sure how to search for them.

Basically I need the app to draw electrical circuits, and if possible, be able to use it to write mathematical equations.

I also need to be a free/open source.

Platform: Microsoft Windows

Thank you!

Comment: Does no one know?

Comment: For which platform? 
I've seen people use Microsoft PowerPoint and a pen tablet to make such videos or give lectures. PowerPoint is not free, but according to [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/116981/80102), Google Slides might launch a similar feature.

On tablets, one could use a combination of pdf annotation software with a screen recorder

Comment: For Windows, on my laptop. I want such a program so that I can draw electrical circuits so using PowerPoint is not an option.

Comment: Then I suggest editing the question to include these important details. Otherwise, you would get less relevant answers or the post could be closed for being too broad